# Spinnaker "enable server group" stage failing

Tags: spinnaker

I am getting `Exception ( Determine Target Server Group )
Path parameter "app" value must not be null.` when enabling server group. Can anyone tell me what I could be doing wrong? I can enable the server manually but when I put it in a stage it fails with the error.

Comment: version halyard and spinnaker??

Comment: @avenda I am on 1.4.2.

Comment: we need more details so we can help you. Are you deploying in kubernetes? plase share hal config ouput.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to spinnaker [version](https://www.spinnaker.io/community/releases/versions/#version-11710) `1.17` That version solves issues with the enable server group stage.

**To Upgrade Spinnaker:**

Access halyard pod 
get pods name

`export HALYARD=$(kubectl -n spinnaker get pod -l app=halyard -oname | cut -d'/' -f 2)`

Access Halyard pod with bash

`kubectl -n spinnaker exec -it ${HALYARD} /bin/bash`

Obtain the version by running Halyard Command

`hal version bom`

Set the version you want to use. Refer to the releases page Versions[1](https://www.spinnaker.io/community/releases/versions/#version-11710)

```
export UPGRADE_VERSION=1.17.6
hal config version edit --version $UPGRADE_VERSION
```

Deploy and apply the new version with hal

`hal deploy apply`